# Application doesnt respond after resuming it

Tags: java, android, android-anr-dialog

My 'game' keeps crashing after I resume it. Basically, I launch the app and everything works. Then I press the home button and go back to my home screen. Still all the normal stuff. But THEN when I open the app back up, it just freezes and after 1 minute or so, I get a not responding message.

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.amzoft.android.starraider;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class StarRaiderMain extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnKeyListener, SensorEventListener{

FastRenderView renderView;
SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor accelerometer;
Thread mainGameThread;

Player player;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    renderView = new FastRenderView(this);
    renderView.setOnKeyListener(this);
    renderView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    renderView.requestFocus();
    setContentView(renderView);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);

    mainGameThread = new Thread(new mainGameThread());

    player = new Player(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    renderView.resume();
    renderView.requestFocus();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    renderView.pause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
{

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    player.onSensorChanged(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    player.onKey(v, keyCode, event);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{

    return true;
}

class FastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
{
    Thread renderThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    public FastRenderView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
    }

    public void resume()
    {
        running = true;
        renderThread = new Thread(this);
        renderThread.start();
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        running = false;
        while(true)
        {
            try{
                renderThread.join();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                Log.d("StarRaider", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            onDraw(canvas);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
        player.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
class mainGameThread extends Thread
{
    mainGameThread()
    {
        super("mainGameThread");
        start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try{
            player.onUpdate();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenie]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my logcat output: http://pastebin.com/3b09YAkP
I have a main game thread, because I read that if the render thread gets stuck for 2 seconds, it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it might be one of two things.

You should probably be explicitly pausing your thread in `onPause()`.  That might cause application deadlock if it tries to resume without having been paused.

You should also take a look at the Google I/O presentation on Replica Island.  It's about an hour long.  Take note of the part where he talks about garbage collection.  This might be what's happening and causing your app to crash because of an ANR error.

I hope this helps!

Comment: how do i explicitly pause it?

Comment: Please read this article: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: k, I got rid of the entire while loop in the pause method in my FastRenderView inner class. It seems to work now, but is there anything else i could do? I have a book on android game development, and I have learnt the basics. But now the book wants to write a whole framework and i really cant be asked to, because it suddenly assumes that i know what all the stuff it is talking about. I want to make this game, and then read the section on OpenGL ES.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure.  I am just learning OpenGL ES myself, so I can't speak to that.  I'm glad you fixed your problem though!

Comment: Yes, thanks. Can you provide me with a link to the I/O video?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk  I learned a lot in just an hour watching this :)

Answer (score 0):

May be related to this bug http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2566